# is it possible to find a monic quadratic polynomial that factors in Z but not in Z3?

Tags: polynomials, modules, quadratics, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Only using integer coefficients, is it possible to find a monic quadratic polynomial that factors normally but doesn’t factor in field/mod 3?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 2):

No.  If we had $$x^2 + Ax + B = (x+a)(x+b)$$ over $\mathbb{Z}$, then we'd have $$x^2+[A]x+[B] = (x+[a])(x+[b])$$ over $\mathbb{Z}/(3\mathbb{Z})$, where $[x] = x+3\mathbb{Z}$ is the quotient map.

---

This is true just because $x \mapsto x+3\mathbb{Z} : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/(3\mathbb{Z})$ is a ring homomorphism, and as such, it can generalize to any ring homomorphism (at least for monic polynomials, to avoid one factor becoming a unit).